# how do i pass a plsql exit code to a shell variable?

Tags: shell, unix, plsql, exit-code, bind-variables

My code traps various exit codes for various conditions and stores the value to a local  variable; I'm then passing it to a bind var which I am using to store the exit code.
My code is something like:

```
variable errflag number
   begin
      variable vflag number;
         if
           cond 1
           then
              vflag:=1;
             .
             .
             .
             .
              .
          elsif
            cond n
               then
                 vflag:=n;
               else
                 ...do nothing..
              end if;
              :errflag:=vflag;
end;
/
             exit :errflag
```

but I am getting the below error after running

> SP2-0670: Internal number conversion failed Usage: { EXIT | QUIT }  [
>   SUCCESS | FAILURE | WARNING | n |
>           | : ]  [ COMMIT | ROLLBACK ]

any ideas??? :\

Comment: How did you plan on executing that?

Comment: i got it James. There was a small error in my shell script which was prompting the error.

I was using bash instead of ksh.